# XPages - Bootstrap: aligning fields on one line

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to do a small "Search: [field]  [button]" type of "search bar with the Boostrap theme found in the latest Extension library, but I guess I am missing something, as all controls appear on top of each other on different lines and not on a single one.

I am not yet familiar with Bootstrap (doing a phonebook with it as first app, hence the search feature), and I couldn't get it workling as I want with the various posts I have read so far, as they add style to the "form" element...

Here is the code I have, that makes the label appear on top, then the field on a subsequent line, then the button on another line:

```
<xp:panel style="width:400px" >
    <xp:label value="Recherche :" id="label2" xp:key="label" style="font-weight:bold" styleClass="form-control-static">
    </xp:label>
    <xp:inputText id="searchFor"
        value="#{sessionScope.searchFor}" styleClass="form-control-static">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onkeypress" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="PanelMain">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:inputText>
    <xp:button value="Reset" id="button1"
            styleClass="btn btn-primary form-control-static">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="PanelMain">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.searchFor = null;}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:panel>
```

What Am I missing?  I am not using a form table layout, as you can see: tried it and it didn't work as I wanted...  I even tried  "display:inline", without success.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really an XPages question, but more about applying the required Bootstrap classes. Did you look at the inline form example here (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)? I would compare that to the output that your code generates.

Comment: Mark, I did, but since I am using XPages elements, I wasn't sure how to incorporate the bootstrap classes to the various xpages elements.  From the answer Chris gave, I guess I'll have to do a lot "manually" (html code inside the xpage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick and dirty code I just knocked up and everything displays on one line and only starts dropping onto multiple lines when resizing a smaller browser window.

I am however using some actual bootstrap HTML, to build up my own row and grid....

```
<!-- ROW 1 --> 
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="edtName">Name:</label>
        <xp:inputText id="edtName">
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="placeholder" value="Name"></xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>
        </xp:inputText>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
<xp:button value="Search" id="btnSearch" styleClass="btn btn-success btn-   block btn-tall">

<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
    refreshId="divReset">
<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var strName:string = getComponent("edtName").getValue();
viewScope.searchString = strName
}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
</div>
</div>
```